# Creating and opening a Word Document using Access 2007 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to output an Access 2007 report to Word (using .rtf!) but I can't seem to then point my code at the file. I keep getting Type Mismatch errors.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CatalogTitle_Click()
Dim AppWord As Object
Dim Doc As Object
Dim FileName As String
Dim DateTime As Date
Dim DTString As String
Dim x As Integer


Set AppWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")  ' create an instance     of Word

DateTime = Now()             ' build a date string which is compatible with the Windows File structure
DTString = CStr(DateTime)

For x = 1 To Len(DTString)   ' changes dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss into dd_mm_yy hh_mm_ss
    If (Mid(DTString, x, 1) = "/" Or Mid(DTString, x, 1) = ":") Then
        Mid(DTString, x, 1) = "_"
    End If
Next x

' build the full .rtf filename
FileName = "Titles " & DTString & ".rtf"

' and output the rtf file to it
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "ItemsReportByTitle", acFormatRTF, FileName

' then open the Word instance with the file just created
Set Doc = "AppWord.Documents.Open(FileName)"

' and make the instance visible
AppWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

I keep failing on the 'Set Doc...' line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes around the object/method...

```
Set Doc = AppWord.Documents.Open(FileName)
```

Comment: Wow! That made a massive difference. Thank you!